# Finding Variable Data from Local Text File

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to write a Dungeons and Dragon program.

I am attempting to write data to a file that is read at the time the application is launched. The application is currently a console application, if that makes any difference. I also want the file to be able to be updated, either by completely rewriting the file, or by appending the new information to the end of the file.

Currently, the text file is laid at like so:

```
Character: Harvey
MaxHP : 120
CurrentHP: 80
STR: 10
DEX: 8
CON: 6
INT: 4
WIS: 9
CHA: 12

Character: Dent
MaxHP : 182
CurrentHP: 120
STR: 10
DEX: 1
CON: 8
INT: 10
WIS: 18
CHA: 20
```

How, would I read the information so that I can get ABC's stats from the file and stored into a List, and then get DEF's start and store it separately so I am able to call them.

I am relatively new to C#, and this is my first time trying to read and write to files. I've tried Googling but haven't been able to understand how to find information within a file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're just reading lines of data from a text file then `File.ReadAllLines()` sounds like a reasonable place to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8  It'll read in the entire file into an array of strings.  Then you can loop through the array and parse out the data you need into your model structure.

Comment: If you aren't tied to that format, consider using a more standard format like XML or JSON.  For example, you can create a `List<UserInfo>`, pass it to the Newtonsoft JSON serializer and end up with nicely parsable JSON (which you can read in with the corresponding deserializer).  Letting someone else with a tested serializer and parser do that work for you is a good thing.

Comment: +1 to using JSON. Powerful libraries exist to deserialize JSON to objects. However, using a text file in this way may be a good learning exercise. It depends on your goals

Comment: To be honest, using JSON seems to be the best option. But I also wanted to more understand how to go through data in C#. I've seen the `File.ReadAllLines()` on the Microsoft, but I'm not sure how I would go through each string and tell it there's a number and it is for the STR property, or that this number is for the DEX property. I would really appreciate this being explained as it would greatly improve my knowledge of C#.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest storing your characters formatted with json, like this

```
[
  {
    "Name" : "Harvey",
    "MaxHP" : 120,
    "CurrentHP" : 80,
    "STR" : 10,
    "DEX" : 8,
    "CON" : 6,
    "INT" : 4,
    "WIS" : 9,
    "CHA" : 12
  },
  {
    "Name" : "Dent",
    "MaxHP" : 182,
    "CurrentHP" : 120,
    "STR" : 10,
    "DEX" : 1,
    "CON" : 8,
    "INT" : 10,
    "WIS" : 18,
    "CHA" : 20
  },
]
```

With a matching class like this

```
public class Character
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int MaxHP { get; set; }
  public int CurrentHP { get; set; }
  public int STR { get; set; }
  public int DEX { get; set; }
  public int CON { get; set; }
  public int INT { get; set; }
  public int WIS { get; set; }
  public int CHA { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use a library to parse it, either [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) or the newly added [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to). You would then have a `List<Character>` to use. This way you can access the various stats on each character directly, instead of trying to find it in a list of stats for each character.

**Edit**

If you are using Dotnet Core 3+ I would recommend `System.Text.Json`, as it is the new built in library. You can find usage for deseralization [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#how-to-read-json-into-net-objects-deserialize). As an example, you could use it like this

```
//Synchronous
string fileText = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Path\To\File.txt");
List<Character> characters = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Character>>(fileText);
```

```
//Asynchronous
using (Filestream fs = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Path\To\File.txt")
{
  List<Character> characters = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Character>>(fs);
}
```

If you are using Newtonsoft (also known as `Json.NET`) it might look like this (taken from the above Newtonsoft link)

```
//Synchronous
string fileText = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Path\To\File.txt");
List<Character> characters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Character>>(fileText);
```

Comment: Thanks for the amazing response. I'm not at all familiar with JSON or Newtonsoft. Could you give an example of using either of these, like the syntax?

Comment: Added some usage examples to my answer